# How to emulate visio containers?

Tags: c#, visio

I`m writing C# winforms application, which uses visio control to create diagrams. And right now I need to implement containers similar to containers in Visio 2010 or bands in cross-functional diagrams.

Requiments are to make them look identically in Visio 2007 and 2010 and to prevent user from making 2 lanes by draggin them aside.

I`m planing to create new shape in my stencil, but how to:

- glue 1 container to another`s side - not just connection point?
- control, which shapes belong given container? just checking boundaries of each shape in code?
- move conteiner with all shapes inside? just making movement inside code or it can be done via visio settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this blog post from the Visio team. 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visio/archive/2010/01/12/custom-containers-lists-and-callouts-in-visio-2010.aspx
Create the shapes you want in a stencil rather than trying to create the shapes from scratch and just use C# to place and customize the shape.

John... Visio MVP

Comment: Thank you, it is very interesting article, but it`s completely about visio 2010. And I need to create "container" in 2007 version as well...